# Which Design Pattern to use in this multi-threaded scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, program-entry-point

I have 3 algorithms - let's call them A, B, C. Each of these have their own getter and setter methods e.g. `A` might have `getA()`/`setA()` same goes for B and C.
There is a `MainDriver` class which creates an instance of either A, B, or C depending on what is passed as a command line argument to this `MainDriver` class. 
`MainDriver` class creates multiple threads to execute the methods of the algorithm whose instance is created. Thus, when this algorithm instance is created, it passes this instance to a class that extends the Thread class so that each individual thread may execute public methods of that algorithm.

Now my question is which Design Pattern should I use to implement this architecture?

How will the thread class knows which algorithm instance is passed to it as an argument and accordingly which getter and setter method to execute?

Comment: It would be better if upload your code. The question is more of a opinion based. Answer to your question would change with the requirement.

Comment: look up the gang of four book on design patterns

Comment: @GabrieleB-David: "look-up gang of four book" - not very helpful!

Comment: @BeginnersSake: I agree, but what is your opinion given these requirements..

Comment: @ShreyasGokhale Before posting on stackoverflow, you should do research on your problem so instead of just telling you to go see the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask) page I suggested a resource so you can find the answer to your problem. And who knows, if you do find the GoF book, you might even learn more than the answer you're looking for

Comment: @GabrieleB-David, I was not sure about which design patterns to use in this scenario and that is why I posted my question here. I already knew about that gang of four book. Clearing up our confusion/doubts - isn't that why we post our questions here??

Comment: How about using a factory pattern where the input parameter passed decides the algo instance to be created and properties being set accordingly? That would let you decouple the implementation logic for the algo classes (so that it's easy to plug-in and out different impl) from its usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with you can create an hierarchy for all your algirithms. e.g. BaseAlgo is interface and all concrete Algos will implement the same.

Your Thread subclass can refer to BaseAlgo("has a relationship") and you can invoke methods on the concrete Algo object that you pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

Any Event/Asynchronous oriented "Architecture" would solve your problem very easily, enabling you to focus on your business code instead of the mechanic.

Tell me if i'm wrong but we can resume your specifications like this:

- depending on an argument, execute a specific program
- the selected program must be executed in a seperate thread

For example, Reactor (fully integrated with last version of Spring now) offers many ways to do this in an event oriented programming style.

1. Multithreading will be already handled for you. You just care about configuration of your pools (if you need specific behaviour, but default one would match your requirements)
2. You only develop your "algorithm" components, which is nothing else than a component doing some specific code. Each of these components listen to specific event thrown by your main program. Nothing else.